# Azure domain being indexed by google

Tags: azure, dns, robots.txt

I have a website that has a domain 'example.azurewebsites.net'.  I also have a custom domain configured for it 'www.example.com'.  Google is indexing my 'example.azurewebsites.net' website and I want it to stop and only index it has 'www.example.com'.  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you like to use **www.yoursite.com** rather then **yoursite.azurewebsites.net**. If so, you can place this rule to your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
```

```
 <rules>

   <rule name="SEOAzureRewrite" stopProcessing="true">

     <match url=".*" />

     <conditions>

       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^oldwebsite.azurewebsites.net$" />

     </conditions>

     <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.new-web-site.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />

   </rule>

 </rules>
```

ref: http://4sln.com/Articles/how-to-create-a-url-rewrite-rule-for-azure-websites-to-use-single-custom-domain

Comment: I have added this to my `ghost` blog on `Azure` but now when I try logging as admin to `http://MyBlog.com/ghost/admin` I get the `The page isn't redirecting properly` error. Do I need to handle https differently?

Answer (score 1):

I guess **change of address tool** it's what you are after. 
Have a look at this https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en

You can also return a dynamic robots.txt based on domain:

example.azurewebsites.net/robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

www.example.com/robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

Example [here](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Daniel-Osterhof/Dates/2011/6/Ensure-correct-Google-indexing-when-using-multiple-domain-names/)

But change of address tool is probably better.